# Conditional Independence proof

Tags: probability, independence

I am trying to solve the following textbook exercise:
prove that $\Pr(a\;|\;b,c)=\Pr(a\;|\;b)$ and $\Pr(b\;|\;a,c)=P(b\;|\;a)$ implies $\Pr(c\;|\;a,b) = \Pr(c)$ for distinct events $a,b,c$ in a given probability space.

I could not prove this proposition since I conjured multiple counter examples to it. One counter example I have is $\Pr(a)=0.8$, $\Pr(b)=0.4$, $\Pr(a,c)=0.4$, $\Pr(b,c)=0.2$, $\Pr(c)=0.6$, $\Pr(a,b)=0.1$ and $\Pr(a,b,c)=0.05$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  You need to include your work, or at least what you know about the situation, so that people answering you don't explain things you already know or talk over your head.  Transcribing your homework word for word tends to get people downvotes and fewer answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does not abide by the axioms of probability. Writing $\neg a$ for the event complementary to $a$, so that $P(\neg a) = 1-P(a)$, the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) implies
$$P(a, \neg b) = P(a)-P(a, b) = 0.8-0.1 = 0.7$$
and
$$P(\neg a, b) = P(b)-P(a, b) = 0.4-0.1 = 0.3$$
which in turn implies the contradiction
$$1 = P(a) + P(\neg a) = P(a, b)+P(a, \neg b)+P(\neg a, b)+P(\neg a, \neg b) \geq 0.1+0.7+0.3 > 1 \,.$$

Still, **the statement in your textbook is false**: take any dependent events $a$ and $c$ and take $b$ to be identical to $a$. Then the assumptions
$$P(a \mid b, c) = P(a \mid b) \quad \text{and} \quad P(b \mid a,c) = P(b \mid a)$$
are always trivially satisfied since
$$P(a \mid b, c) = P(a \mid a, c) = 1 = P(a \mid a)$$
and similarly for the second one. However we have
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #A06000]{P(c \mid a,b) = P(c \mid a) \neq P(c)}$$
by assumption of dependency between $a$ and $c$. [To be concrete, consider an urn with 2 red balls and 2 blue balls. Let $a = b$ be the event that the first ball we pick from the urn is red, and let $c$ be the event that the second ball we pick from the urn is red. These events are dependent.]

Comment: Maybe you also want to improve the now closed question to help the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have just done so!

Comment: thanks very much for the formal treatment of the question.  It helps tremendously!